# Looking for ASA members to interview about the usefulness of CV

Tags: discussion

In an effort to achieve more visibility within statistical communities, SE is thinking of writing about CV in an ASA (American Statistical Association) magazine, assuming the ASA would be interested.  This would potentially reach most university level stats teachers, researchers, and many professional statisticians in business, government, and consulting in the US.

Please use this thread to offer your reactions, suggestions, and any other related ideas.  It would be useful to hear about what points you think ought to be made in such an article: why should statisticians be interested in participating?  What, in your opinion, is uniquely beneficial about this site?

If you are an ASA member and would be willing to be interviewed or quoted for an article, please contact Seth Rogers (seth@stackexchange.com).  This is low key: there's no commitment and you won't have to write anything (unless you want to help!).

Comment: For a little more information, a [brief chat transcript](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18/conversation/interview-discussion) about this idea is available.

Comment: After communicating with the ASA members magazine editor, they are indeed interested in an article containing interviews with researchers/statisticians who use CV as a resource. If CV has been a valuable resource in your work, let us know how!

Comment: I'm an ASA member, and I started CV. Happy to be interviewed if there is interest.

Answer (score 1):

Frank Harrell is obviously the biggest name statisticians would recognize. He does post on CV from time to time. Frankly, I am not sure as to who else would be highly visible in ASA. I am an ASA member, but if you look at what I do on CV you'd find out that I don't post and only reply -- I don't think that's the mode of presence that a median user would have.

Comment: Thanks, Stas.  We're not looking for "median users" or even typical users.  In fact, you're actually quite active: by "post" I mean generically a reply, comment, or a question (and I doubt any ASA member would interact on this site primarily by asking questions).  Remember, the SE folks don't really know the ASA, so if they are going to gather information about CV that might be of interest to ASA members, it would be best for them to talk to ASA members!  You would be a good candidate for that.

Comment: By "post" I meant, "ask questions". Most of the time, if I have statistical/methodology questions, I know exactly the person who can answer them, so ask them directly, and they won't be on CV, anyway. If you think I am a good face to show up in AmStat News, I'll be happy to chat with whomever is doing the article.

Comment: @Stask Maybe the idea would be to introduce those persons you know to SE, through the ASA network?